# Передача данных в платжную систему

Tags: curl, php

Как правильно передать данные в платежную систему:

Язык php.

сначала думали использовать cUrl, что бы не светить все данные, но немного разобравшись с ним понял, что он то передаст данные, но меня не отправит на страницу где дальше производить оплату.

Выходит надо на страницу выводить форму и указывать в ней все параметры. А как тогда быть с секретными словами и другими token'ами? Заранее формировать? Но если даже и сформировать данные, то в форме видно какая платежная система используется и из открытых источников можно узнать метод шифрования. Сможет ли в таком случае злоумышленник перехватить данные, расшифровать? Как обезопасить себя в этом случае?

Comment: что он то передаст данные, но меня не отправит на страницу где дальше производить оплату.   - это пачиму?

вообще в чем конкретно вопрос и собственно где код который уже есть?

Comment: Правильно передать данные в платёжную систему — как написано в документации к п.с. и её api. Скажем, с Робокассой или Ассистом пользователь перенаправляется по ссылке, содержащей в себе данные для оформления счёта: номер заказа, сумму к оплате. А подтвеждение оплаты приходит от п.с. на специальный URL вашего сайта, с цифровой подписью, которую обязательно проверяют, прежде, чем поверить, что «заказ 321 оплачен».

Comment: Спасибо за ответы и комментарии. Вопрос скорее заключался в том, как передать данные в POST запросе не засветив их в форме на сайте? Anton Dobkin правильно сказал по поводу шифрования и секретных слов. Но мне же надо как-то передать эту зашифрованную строку в запросе. Как это сделать, если нужен переход по ссылке это и там уже пользователь будет дальше вводить номера счетов своих и пр.?

Answer (score 1):

Большинство платежных систем используют подпись данных. Вам выдается (или вы сами задаете в настройка ПС на ее сервере) некий ключ. Это ключ известен только вам и серверу платежной системы, данный ключ НИКОГДА не передается в запросе.

Вы показываете некую форму пользователю, пользователь ее заполняет и нажимает кнопку "отправить", далее ВАШ скрипт проверяет заполненость необходимых полей и формирует строку запроса к серверу ПС. Обычно запрос - это значения полей заполненных пользователем (сумма, валюта) + данные продавца (название магазина, ID и т.д.) + подпись.

Подпись, например, это md5 от всех значений обязательных полей и секретного ключа разделенных неким символом: `md5(fielfd1::field2::field3::secret_key)`. Алгоритм получения подписи описывается в документации к ПС

Если ПС требует переправить пользователя на сервер ПС, для подтверждения платежа,  тогда вы формируете еще одну форму со скрытыми полями, необходимыми для передачи + подпись. Форма может быть отправлена с помощью JavaScript или же можно добавить кнопку "Подтвердить", на которую пользователь должен нажать для  подтверждения платежа.

Сервер приняв данные от вас также создает подпись по тому же алгоритму что и вы, используя секретный ключ. Полученная подпись сравнивается с той что передана в запросе, если она не совпадает то платеж не  будет завершен. Также платежная система может послать вам "фоновый" запрос для подтверждения платежа, на который вы должны ответить неким кодом.

Если перенаправление пользователя не требуется, то вы можете отправить запрос на сервер ПС используя curl

Есть платежные системы которые используют персональные  SSL сертификаты для установки связи магазин <->сервер ПС.

Это приближенное описание.  Каждая ПС имеет свою документацию в которой описан алгоритм работы и алгоритмы проверки данных